# How can i implement a InterlockedIncrement without a memory barrier

Tags: c, multithreading, interlocked

I implement a reference counting schema and for this i need interlock facilities but no memory  fences (as far as i understand).

Unfortunately only Windows has a InterlockedDecrementNoFence compiler intrinsic.
How can i do this with asm inlining? I would need this for gcc/clang too.

Comment: Um... Inline assembly is going to be different in MSVC and gcc anyway... And the barrier is better kept where it belongs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lack of at least an intrinsic memory fence operation (depending on the platform) is pretty much going to be impossible for the semantics of this operation.  For an atomic increment/decrement to work, the other processor have to have some guarantee of seeing the value of the atomic operation before they perform their own operations on the variable, and the visibility of the operations on the variable has to have some guaranteed total order.  Memory barriers, even implicit ones such as in strong-memory models like x86 where standard memory operations have acquire/release semantics, are paramount to the correctness of an atomic increment/decrement operation.

Keep in mind that even when the documentation for MSVC/gcc says that there is a memory barrier, on x86 there will not be an actual memory barrier applied (i.e., a `MFENCE` instruction) due to the strong-memory model of the platform, but rather a lock on the memory bus to ensure the atomicity of the operation.  IA64 on the other-hand will require a memory barrier due to the weaker memory model of that platform.  The same would also be true for ARM.

Comment: So i did missunderstand the concept of Barriers. Because i thought it will only effect the ordering of pending different read/write operations. And with refcounting there is no ordering problem at all because only one memory location is involved. And that is already solved by the cache coherence protocol in case of multiprocessor systems.

Comment: Keep in mind I said "intrinsic" barrier ... depending on the platform there may not be an explicit memory barrier operation, but you still pay the penalty as-if there was one since you have to make the results of the atomic operation visible to every other processor, and every atomic operation must have a total order on a given memory address.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a direct answer but an alternative proposal. If you can use C11 (or C++11), how about atomic operations with `memory_order_relaxed`? Your compiler *may* generate no memory fence on weak memory model platforms. (It depends compiler vendor/version)

```
#include <stdatomic.h>

atomic_int var;
int oldval;

oldval = atomic_fetch_sub_explicit(&var, 1, memory_order_relaxed);
```